# How does stackoverflow manage tags

Tags: mysql, performance, database-design, tags

I am interested in the underlying data structure of the database and the way stackoverflow manages tags. I am about to build application that will rely entirely on tag based filters and I seek for the right approach. What is the best way to design the database, so a minimum queries will have to run in future when working with the sets of tags to filter my data. I did use the search, but couldn't find what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stackoverflow does not rely entirely on SQL database to work with tags. They cache, pre-sort and pre-aggregate them aggressively.

Read this [interesting story of one optimization](http://samsaffron.com/archive/2011/10/28/in-managed-code-we-trust-our-recent-battles-with-the-net-garbage-collector).

From there you can get some insights on how stackoverflow works.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if they do it well, but you may want to look at Drupal taxonomy for ideas (http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/taxonomy). If you run the installation, you can look at how they handle this in the generated db.